# How the server make sure clients requests doesn't interfere with each other?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, concurrency

I got an interview question, how the server manages to not make clients requests intercept with each other?

I couldn't actually answer that, because I didn't find the answer online.

I thought the cause of parrel requests/async calls/concurrency or threading.

But I don't have a real answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question right but this article explains the single-threaded model of nodeJS pretty nicely imo ([node-js-architecture-single-threaded-event-loop](https://www.journaldev.com/7462/node-js-architecture-single-threaded-event-loop))

**tldr**:

NodeJS has a single thread for the event loop. I'm not sure about the specific data structure implementations but every request is added to a queue where it's picked up by the event loop, executed and response sent.

If the request performs blocking IO (or other blocking processes*), the operation is handed over to a different thread, the request is put in some waiting list and the event loop picks up a different request to handle. Once the blocking op is done, the event loop picks up the original request and plus the results of the op, continues processing the request then sends a response.

* If the blocking process is procedurally coded by you, you could end up blocking the event loop causing a DOS. One should use a worker thread for that.

** NodeJS also has the concept of multithreading using the cluster module so there's that but it's still generally considered single-threaded.